# Prove $P(N_{na} < n) \leq (aλe^{1−λa})^n$ in Poisson process.

Tags: probability, poisson-process

Here is the question I meet.

Let $N = (N_t, t > 0)$ be a Poisson Process of rate $λ ∈ (0, ∞)$.

Show that for all
$a ∈ (0, ∞)$ and $n ∈ N$,

$P(N_{na} < n) \leq (aλe^{1−λa})^n$

I found that when $n=1$, $P(N_{a} < 1) = e^{-λa}$.

Comparing to $aλe^{1−λa}$,  I think the question is wrong.

Is there any problem in my process? Thanks.

Also, I was given the hint that combining mgf and Markov's inequality, but I have no idea how they are related.

Comment: Based on some arbitrary values I substituted I don't think the statement is true in general.